# Why does SecretManager not have service role wheareas it has interactions with many services?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-rds, amazon-cloudwatch, aws-secrets-manager

I'm working on AWS service role.  And i was wondering why secretsmanager doesn't have service role... I thought it was the case, for instance secretsmanager has interaction with lambda, kms AWS config, Amazon RDS services. So why in the doc, it says that for the secretsmanager service we don't need to create a role in the Trust Policy which will perform actions on our behalf, since it has interaction with those services.
Thanks

Comment: What's motivating your question?  Are you looking to do X but can't figure out how because Secrets Manager has no service-linked role?  If so, please describe X in the question.